# ImportError: cannot import name 'is_categorical' from 'pandas.api.types'

Tags: python, pandas, linux

I want to convert `file1.hic` file into `.cool` format using [hic2cool](https://github.com/4dn-dcic/hic2cool), which is written in Python. I converted the files using command line:

```
hic2cool convert file1.hic file1.cool -r 10000
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/melchua/.local/bin/hic2cool", line 5, in <module>
    from hic2cool.__main__ import main
  File "/home/melchua/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hic2cool/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .hic2cool_utils import (
  File "/home/melchua/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hic2cool/hic2cool_utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cooler
  File "/home/melchua/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cooler/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .api import Cooler, annotate
  File "/home/melchua/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cooler/api.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .core import (get, region_to_offset, region_to_extent, RangeSelector1D,
  File "/home/melchua/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cooler/core.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas.api.types import is_categorical
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_categorical' from 'pandas.api.types' (/home/melchua/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/api/types/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Can you provide your file1.hic please? I tested with python==3.9.16, hic2cool==0.8.3 and pandas==(2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.5.3, 1.4.4, 1.2.5, 0.25) with the [test file](https://github.com/4dn-dcic/hic2cool/blob/master/test_data/test_hic.hic) and everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of `pandas 2.0.1` seems to not have `is_categorical` but instead it has `is_categorical_dtype`. Seems that in `hic2cool`, `pandas` version is not pinned to the one that has that.

I suggest installing a previous version of `pandas` before the changes took place.

Or install a newer version of `cooler` as they updated their library to use `is_categorical_dtype`

Answer (score 0):

seems like the `is_categorical` function that is being used by `hic2cool`, has been *deprecated* in the newer version of pandas

> Deprecated since version 2.0.0: Use pandas.api.types.is_categorical_dtype() instead.

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.is_categorical.html

You might need to install an older version of `pandas` (< 2) to get this working - since I believe that `hic2cool` hasn't been updated in a long time